# Should we disavow lost backlinks from banned account in reddit?

Tags: backlinks, nofollow, disavow-links

My account in reddit banned and I lost more than 2500 (nofollow) backlinks.
I had 2500 articles with backlinks to my site in reddit that all articles was in google index; But now, I dont't have access to my reddit account because the banned my account and removed all of my posts!!!
What should I do right now ?
I fear that it hurt my site!
Should I Disavow them?

Comment: Please edit your existing question to clarify so that it can be re-opened rather than posting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Do not disavow.

If you don't know what you're doing, disavow can do extremely serious damage to your site and revenue.

The notion that some paid SEO tools can detect spammy sites but Google can't is almost funny. Disavow is no longer necessary as Google detects spammy sites and adds zero weight to those inbound links.

(This of course is a subject of eternal debate, but there's plenty of evidence now to show that this is the case. Still, ask 10 SEOs this question and you'll get 10 different answers.)

Comment: I'm not sure what they are planning to disavow anyway, reddit removed the links, so there is nothing left to disavow.